# Wanting to smooth cv::Mat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1.

I have a cv::Mat image and I would like to apply a smoothing filter.    Unfortunately, all I code find was

```
void cvSmooth(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int smoothtype=CV_GAUSSIAN, int size1=3, int size2=0, double sigma1=0, double sigma2=0 );
```

which uses CvArr instead of cv::Mat.  I could not find an explanation about how to convert between cv::Mat and CvArr.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you load you image as you want, for me I used :

```
image = cvLoadImage("6mtEy.jpg");
```

As far as I know if you want to use this function your gona need to convert your Mat into a cvArr (IplImage in my code) :

```
IplImage tmp = image;
```

Then you create your destination image with the same size etc as your first picture :

```
IplImage *dst;
dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(tmp.width, tmp.height), tmp.depth, tmp.nChannels);
```

Then you use your function :

```
cvSmooth(&tmp, dst, CV_GAUSSIAN, 1);
```

And finally you put the result back in a mat :

```
image = dst;
```

After don't forget to destroy the IplImages you created.

Answer (score 4):

As stated [in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#smooth):

> Note: The function is now obsolete. Use [GaussianBlur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur), [blur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#blur), [medianBlur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#medianblur) or [bilateralFilter()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#bilateralfilter).

For all these functions, C++ interfaces exist, e.g.:

```
void GaussianBlur(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size ksize, double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT )
```